# C# - How come I can use delegates in the class that was not instantiated?

Tags: c#, class, field

I thought that delegate fields are just like other fields and that I cannot use them until the class is instantiated. However:

```
 class Program
    {

        delegate void lol (int A);
         string myX;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            lol x = ... //works     

            myX //does not exist, 
        }
    }
```

Comment: please do not downvote without commet!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
delegate void lol (int A);
```

A Delegate is not a field it is a "Nested Type", So you can use it just like any other types.

And refering to `myX` inside the `Main` is illegal because `myX` is instance field. you need to use instance.myX to use it inside a static method(`Main() here`)

To be more clear, Try the following you'll realize what you're doing wrong

```
class Program
{
    delegate void lol (int A);
     string myX;
     lol l; 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        l = null; //does not exist
        myX //does not exist, 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, It means a Type inside a Type, Class->Class, Class->Struct, Class->Delegate, Struct->Struct, Struct->Delegate, etc

Comment: Dont get me wrong, I know how to use delegates or lambdas, I just realized that I did not know I dont need the instance of Program class (in this case). I always thought about delegate as of another object. String, int are also types (data types).

Comment: No, it is a `Type` always no matter where you declare it. So you don't need a instance to access it

Comment: Don't mistake if I rolled back your valuable edits to my answer, that is not intentionally done. It is due to lack of synchronization primitives :)

Comment: Type of what? I'm still confused.

Comment: @user970696 The declaration `delegate void lol (int A);` does not declare a delegate itself. It declares a `type` which defines the return value type and number of parameters  and their types for a delegate.

Comment: Well, then what is the difference between Object A; and Delegete void A();  ? Both just declare.

Comment: If you mean `System.Object` then `Object A` is declaring a variable. where as `Delegete void A();` is defining a type. `Delegete void A();` is almost equal to `Class A {}`(I say this as a example for creating a type dont confuse)

Comment: I mean, Class A. A b=A();  I have a variable of data type A. ALso if I create an instance of delegate, isnt it a variable of data type delegate?

Comment: Yes if you create instance of delegate it is a variable. but your question shows `delegate void lol (int A);` this is defining a delegate type, this is not a variable

Comment: Oh right, I think I got it. Basically I just declare the data type, not variable of its type.

Answer (score -1):

A delegate instance is an object that refers to one or more target methods.

**lol x = ... THIS WILL CREATE DELEGATE INSTANCE**

```
class Program
{

    delegate void lol (int A);
     string myX;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        lol x = ... // THIS WILL CREATE DELEGATE INSTANCE
        x(3) // THIS WILL INVOKE THE DELEGATE

        myX //does not exist, 
    }
}
```

Another importent delegate Syntaxis I have copied for you from MSDN

```
    // Original delegate syntax required  
    // initialization with a named method.
    TestDelegate testDelA = new TestDelegate(M);

    // C# 2.0: A delegate can be initialized with 
    // inline code, called an "anonymous method." This
    // method takes a string as an input parameter.
    TestDelegate testDelB = delegate(string s) { Console.WriteLine(s); };

    // C# 3.0. A delegate can be initialized with 
    // a lambda expression. The lambda also takes a string 
    // as an input parameter (x). The type of x is inferred by the compiler.
    TestDelegate testDelC = (x) => { Console.WriteLine(x); };
```